# Dockerizing a shiny app with an error in the building process

Tags: r, shiny

I built a shiny app couple of months ago and i've been trying to deploy it into a docker for a while...with no success. I checked some other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406631/deploy-shiny-app-in-rocker-shiny-docker) and some other webs, youtube videos but I always get errors builing it.

One of the things I saw different is the structure of the app. Most of them, not all, have the simplest structure:

-app 
|
|-ui.R 
|-server.R 
dockerfile

A folder called app with both files, ui and server and at the level of the folder the dockerfile.

My structure is a little bit different.

- app

  - renv

    - library
    - activate.R
    - settings.json
  - src

    - Carga_datos.R
    - packages.R
    - Descriptivo_aplicacion.R
  - www

    - image.png
  - server.R
  - ui.R
  - app.R
- dockerfile

My last try with the dockerfile was:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get -y install r-cran-curl && \
    apt-get clean

# copy necessary files
## renv.lock file
COPY /app/renv.lock ./renv.lock


## app folder
COPY /app ./app

# install renv & restore packages
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv")'
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

```
Errors had been changing, every time I try to create the container with the sentence:
```

```
docker build -t actividades .
```

I cannot see the error, to be honest.

Thank in advanced and in case more information is needed...happy to share, even to create a repo in github and give access to the code, no problem at all.

EDIT:

I am adding the last part of the message error:

```
#0 2987.8 Using PKG_LIBS=-lfreetype -lharfbuzz -lfribidi -lpng
#0 2987.8 --------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
#0 2987.8 Configuration failed to find the harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi library. Try installing:
#0 2987.8  * deb: libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
#0 2987.8  * rpm: harfbuzz-devel fribidi-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
#0 2987.8  * csw: libharfbuzz_dev libfribidi_dev (Solaris)
#0 2987.8  * brew: harfbuzz fribidi (OSX)
#0 2987.8 If harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
#0 2987.8 PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi.pc file. If pkg-config
#0 2987.8 is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
#0 2987.8 R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
#0 2987.8 -------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
#0 2987.8 <stdin>:1:10: fatal error: hb-ft.h: No such file or directory
#0 2987.8 compilation terminated.
#0 2987.8 --------------------------------------------------------------------
#0 2987.8 ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
#0 2987.8 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/.renv/1/textshaping’
#0 2987.8 Error: install of package 'textshaping' failed [error code 1]
#0 2987.9 Traceback (most recent calls last):
#0 2987.9 12: renv::restore()
#0 2987.9 11: renv_restore_run_actions(project, diff, current, lockfile, rebuild)
#0 2987.9 10: renv_install_impl(records)
#0 2987.9  9: renv_install_staged(records)
#0 2987.9  8: renv_install_default(records)
#0 2987.9  7: handler(package, renv_install_package(record))
#0 2987.9  6: renv_install_package(record)
#0 2987.9  5: withCallingHandlers(renv_install_package_impl(record), error = function(e) {
#0 2987.9         vwritef("\tFAILED")
#0 2987.9         writef(e$output)
#0 2987.9     })
#0 2987.9  4: renv_install_package_impl(record)
#0 2987.9  3: r_cmd_install(package, path)
#0 2987.9  2: r_exec_error(package, output, "install", status)
#0 2987.9  1: stop(error)
#0 2989.1 Execution halted
------
Dockerfile:32
--------------------
  30 |     # install renv & restore packages
  31 |     RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv")'
  32 | >>> RUN Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'
  33 |
  34 |     # expose port
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

EDIT 2:

Now the dockerfile is compiled, I added:

```
# install renv & restore packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('leaflet', 'dplyr', 'httr', 'jsonlite', 'shinyWidgets', 'shiny', 'stringr', 'tidyverse', 'htmltools', 'leaflet.extras', 'leaflet.extras2', 'raster', 'plotly', 'crosstalk', 'shinydashboard', 'later', 'htmlwidgets'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
```

As suggested by Hailey but now when I try to execute the image:

```
docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 actividades
```

Everything looks fine but when I access to `localhost:3838` I got the error: `object 'tidyverse' not found` which is included in the list of the packages to be installed. Any idea?

Thank you in advance because the problem is evolving :)

Comment: "I cannot see the error, to be honest." -- unfortunately, without that error message, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: Hello @KevinUshey, there is an error, of course! I added in the original description

Answer (score 1):

The docker image is not able to access your R environment to download packages. Instead of using `renv`, try to download each package in your Dockerfile. For example:

```
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
```

Comment: It is not completely solved, but at least now it compiles. I edited the question to include the error I got. thank you @hailey

Comment: @Enrique Did you see any errors when the packages were installing while building the image?

Comment: There are errors concatenated. One package fails, I add it and fails another one...I don't have any clue what might happen. If someone is interested in having access to the repo, More than happy. Nothing to hide! Thanks in advance. – @hailey

Comment: @Enrique Did you remove the `renv::restore()` line?

Comment: I already deleted it, you can see the code [here](https://github.com/Enriqueholgado/ActividadesMadrid) - @hailey