# How to deploy my shiny application (with multiple files) via Docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny, deployment, shinydashboard

I want to deploy a shiny application composed of files `ui` , `server` and `global` via Docker. All the files are in the folder `deploy_test`
I simulated this dataset

```
set.seed(123)
dir.create("deploy_test")
setwd("deploy_test")
mydata_<-data.frame(
  gender=c(rep("Male",50),rep("Female",25)),
  height=c(rnorm(50,1.70,0.05),rnorm(25,1.65,1))
)
saveRDS(mydata_,file = "mydata_.RDS")
```

Here are the contents of my files:

### 1. **UI**

```
source("global.R")

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test of app deployment"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    selectInput("gender","Gender",as.character(unique(mydata_$gender)))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      column(6,plotOutput(
        "plot1"
      )),
      column(6,plotOutput(
        "plot2"
      ))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput(
        "table"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

### 2. **SERVER**

```
source("global.R")

function(input, output, session){
  
  output$plot1<-renderPlot(
    {
      data_<-mydata_%>%filter(
        gender==input$gender
      )
      boxplot(data_$height)
    }
  )
  
  
  output$plot2<-renderPlot(
    {
      data_<-mydata_%>%filter(
        gender==input$gender
      )
      hist(data_$height)
    }
  )
  
  
  output$table<-renderDataTable(
    {
      data_<-mydata_%>%filter(
        gender==input$gender
      )
      data_
    }
  )
  
  
}
```

### 3. **GLOBAL**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
mydata_<-readRDS("mydata_.RDS")
```

### 4. **DOCKERFILE**

Dockerfile is located in the same folder as the Shiny's:

```
# Base image
FROM rocker/shiny

#Make a directory in the container
RUN mkdir /home/shiny-app


# Install dependencies
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('tidyverse','shiny','shinydashboard','DT'))"

COPY . /home/shiny-app/

EXPOSE 8180

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/shiny-app')"]
```

I built my container without any problem:

```
docker build -t deploy_test .
```

When I run it:

```
docker run -p  8180:8180 deploy_test
```

It generate the links:
Listening on http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx

But nothing appears when I access the link:
I got: `La connexion a échoué`

Comment: You've exposed port 8180 from your Docker container and forwarded to the same port on the machine running Docker. But I can't see anywhere in your code that you've told Shiny to run on that port. The default rocker/shiny port seems to be 3838: https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny

Comment: Sorry  @SamR, I am new to Docker (I want to try Docker besides shinyserver). I didn't find enough resources about shiny deployment via Docker. I think folow I tutorial that didn't help me. I'd be grateful if you could give me a hand, or even some leads.

Comment: It's been a while since I last installed Shiny Server, I'm afraid, and I don't think it was using rocker. The most important thing is to replace the port 8180 with the actual port Shiny Server is using, presumably 3838. The GitHub link in my first comment shows what your command might look like. Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406631/deploy-shiny-app-in-rocker-shiny-docker

Comment: The port of `shiny::runApp` is either manually specified (`runApp(.., port=xyz)`, set via `options(shiny.port=xyz)`, or it is randomly generated. When deploying an app to one of the server offerings out there (including the eponymous shiny-server and Posit's Connect), they often use 3838, but this question is creating a docker image to run shiny, there's nothing here that I see that runs one of the actual shiny servers. I think all you may need here (to get to the next step) is change the command to `["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/shiny-app', port=8180)"]`.

Comment: @r2evans I think you're right - though possibly the conclusion is don't use `shiny::runApp()` if you're using the `rocker` image. Instead put the relevant files in `/srv/shiny-server/` in the dockerfile  by replacing `COPY . /home/shiny-app/` with `COPY . /srv/shiny-server/`. Or alternatively by using `docker run  -p 3838:3838 -v .:/srv/shiny-server/` as in the rocker docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several pieces to this: either specify `runApp(.., host=, port=)` or shift to using the built-in shiny-server in the parent image.

## Fix `runApp`

First is that you expose port 8180 but the default of `runApp` may be to randomly assign a port. From [`?runApp`](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/latest/runapp):

```
    port: The TCP port that the application should listen on. If the
          ‘port’ is not specified, and the ‘shiny.port’ option is set
          (with ‘options(shiny.port = XX)’), then that port will be
          used. Otherwise, use a random port between 3000:8000,
          excluding ports that are blocked by Google Chrome for being
          considered unsafe: 3659, 4045, 5060, 5061, 6000, 6566,
          6665:6669 and 6697. Up to twenty random ports will be tried.
```

My guess is that it does not randomly choose 8180, at least not reliably enough for you to count on that.

The second problem is that network port-forwarding using docker's `-p` forwards to the container host, but not to the container's `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). So we also should assign a host to your call to `runApp`. The magic `'0.0.0.0'` in TCP/IP networking means "all applicable network interfaces", which will include those that you don't know about before hand (i.e., the default routing network interface within the docker container). Thus,

```
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/shiny-app',host='0.0.0.0',port=8180)"]
```

When I do that, I'm able to run the container and connect to `http://localhost:8180` and that shiny app works. (Granted, I modified the shiny code *a little* since I don't have your data, but that's tangential.)

FYI, if you base your image on `FROM rocker/shiny-verse` instead of `FROM rocker/shiny`, you don't need to `install.packages('tidyverse')`, which can be a large savings. Also, with both `rocker/shiny` and `rocker/shiny-verse`, you don't need to `install.packages('shiny')` since it is already included. Two packages saved.

## Use the built-in shiny-server

The recommended way to use `rocker/shiny-verse` is to put your app in `/srv/shiny-server/appnamegoeshere`, and use the already-functional shiny-server baked in to the docker image.

Two benefits, one consequence:

- Benefit #1: you can deploy and serve multiple apps in one docker image;
- Benefit #2: if/when the shiny fails or exits, the built-in shiny-server will automatically restart it; when `runApp(.)` fails, it stops. (Granted, this is governed by restart logic of shiny in the presence of clear errors in the code.)
- Consequence: your local browser must include the app name in the URL, as in `http://localhost:8180/appnamegoeshere`. The `http://localhost:8180` page is a mostly-static landing page to say that shiny-server is working, and it does not by default list all of the apps that are being served by the server.

This means that your `Dockerfile` could instead be this:

```
# Base image
FROM rocker/shiny-verse

# Install dependencies (tidyverse and shiny are already included)
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinydashboard', 'DT'))"

# Make a directory in the container
RUN mkdir /srv/shiny-server/myapp
COPY . /srv/shiny-server/myapp
```

That's it, nothing more required to get everything you need since `CMD` is already defined in the parent image. Because shiny-server defaults to port 3838, your run command is now

```bash
docker run -p 3838:3838 deploy_test
```

and your local browser uses `http://localhost:3838/myapp` for browsing.

(FYI, the order of `RUN` and other commands in a `Dockerfile` can be influential. If, for instance, you change anything *before* the `install.packages(.)`, then when you re-build the image it will have to reinstall those packages. Since we're no longer needing to (re)install `"tidyverse"` this should be rather minor, but if you stick with `rocker/shiny` and you have to `install.packages("tidyverse")`, then this can be substantial savings. By putting the `RUN` and `COPY` commands for this app *after* `install.packages(..)`, then if we rename the app and/or add more docker commands later, then that `install.packages` step is cached/preserved and does not need to be rerun.)